# When i run app on device i get plugin_Not_Installed Exception in ionic

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

When i run app on device i get plugin_Not_Installed Exception

my ionic info is as below,
Ionic:

Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 6.2.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 14.1.2
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 14.1.2
@angular/cli                  : 14.1.2
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 6.1.0

Cordova:

Cordova CLI       : 11.0.0
Cordova Platforms : android 10.1.2
Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0,
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0,
(and 5 other plugins)

Utility:

cordova-res : 0.15.4
native-run  : not installed

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
NodeJS            : v18.7.0
npm               : 8.6.0
OS                : Windows 10

my packagejson is as below

```
{
  "name": "testapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.0.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/onesignal": "^5.44.0",
    "@ionic-native/onesignal": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/pdf-generator": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^6.1.9",
    "@ionic/cordova-builders": "^7.0.0",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^14.0.3",
    "onesignal-cordova-plugin": "^2.11.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.1.2",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^14.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.3.0",
    "cordova-android": "^10.1.2",
    "cordova-pdf-generator": "^2.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.3",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.7.3"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-pdf-generator": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "onesignal-cordova-plugin": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

my app.component.ts code is as below,

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { OneSignal } from '@ionic-native/onesignal/ngx';
import { Platform, AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private platform: Platform, private splashScreen: SplashScreen, private statusBar: StatusBar, private oneSignal: OneSignal, private alertCtrl: AlertController) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
      setTimeout(() => { this.splashScreen.hide(); }, 1000);
      if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
        this.setupPush();
      }
    });
  }

  setupPush() {
    this.oneSignal.startInit("APPID", "GOOGLEPROJECTID");

    this.oneSignal.inFocusDisplaying(this.oneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.None);
 
    // Notifcation was received in general
    this.oneSignal.handleNotificationReceived().subscribe(data => {
      let msg = data.payload.body;
      let title = data.payload.title;
      let additionalData = data.payload.additionalData;
      this.showAlert(title, msg, additionalData.task);
    });
 
    // Notification was really clicked/opened
    this.oneSignal.handleNotificationOpened().subscribe(data => {
      // Just a note that the data is a different place here!
      let additionalData = data.notification.payload.additionalData;
 
      this.showAlert('Notification opened', 'You already read this before', additionalData.task);
    });
 
    this.oneSignal.endInit();

    this.oneSignal.getIds().then(identity => {
      alert('inside');
      this.showAlert('pushToken : ', identity.pushToken, 'Ok');
      alert(identity.pushToken + ' it is PUSHTOKEN'); 
      alert(identity.userId + 'it is USERID');
    }).catch((e) => {
      alert('in exception!')
      alert(e);
    });


  }

  async showAlert(title, msg, task) {
    const alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
      header: title,
      subHeader: msg,
      buttons: [
        {
          text: `Action: ${task}`,
          handler: () => {`enter code here`
            
          }
        }
      ]
    })
    alert.present();
  }



}
```

Please help me, Thanks

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LZb8r5nfldoNR_EDsys0JvtwA4Vi3gaL/view?usp=sharing

Comment: on which plugin you getting this error?

Comment: this.oneSignal.getIds() => in this line it goes to exception and saying plugin_not_installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem caused mainly from  `@ionic-native/pdf-generator` because
it depends on `@ionic-native/core`...
and there's another problem from onesignal I changed the packages to

```
ionic cordova plugin add onesignal-cordova-plugin@2.11
npm install @ionic-native/onesignal@5.27
```

And you have some problems in general with the images none of them were exist so I hint them.

you can check the source code from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-8qSgLHBN8UfJXYUMBhL8QYpaou7s2XK/view?usp=sharing).

```
npm i
ionic cordova build android
```

[image]

Comment: tried installing cordova-res... still getting the same error!!!

Comment: can you send a picture for the error and what's the command your typing?

Comment: i am issuing the command => ionic cordova build android   to build the apk file and install it in android mobile and checking it... i am not able to attach screenshot here...it is not pasting

Comment: edit your question to add the screenshot

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LZb8r5nfldoNR_EDsys0JvtwA4Vi3gaL/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Apk file ==> 
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VWAKl1wQw8f_0_sYvBneNjL9l0FfV1st/view?usp=sharing

Comment: can you share your code into github ?

Comment: Sure Just a minute

Comment: I'm waiting for you

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jtE-22dLm5_HZNHD5yq2w6Tydfd5gRK1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Just a minute I'll be back

Comment: And I fixed it, I'll upload it for you and I'll update my answer :D

Comment: I updated my answer with the new source code I make some edits in general hope you find them useful and if it's work don't forget to set it as a right answer and please upvote the answer :D

Comment: just downloaded your code and issues npm i then build the apk and tested i am not getting the popup which is inside the then part of getIds.

Comment: check onesignal ids in the config file

Comment: Yeap... Updated that & checked... didnt get the pushToken alert!!!

Comment: why do you want the push token?, in new version you only get the device id and it's working if it's exist no worries.

Comment: You can check that I console the whole data that get from ids and it's only a string, I've built many apps using `onesignal` if the id exists it's worked you can test it.

Comment: I've add a screenshot for it you can check it.

Comment: basically i want to capture the deviceid and store it in db... so that in api i will invoke the onsigal api and send message.... for that purpose i am trying....

Comment: you can store the id and use it to send a message...

Comment: Yeap.. As of now it is not showing the Ids in alert.....this.oneSignal.getIds().then(ids => {
      alert(ids);
      console.log('ids', ids);
      this.showAlert('pushToken : ', ids.pushToken, 'Ok');
    });

Comment: let me check it just a sec

Comment: please check this source code I changed the plugins please do this commands:

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-EK_TruNa5tJGdBSY-alhOIPi8JAs2lY/view?usp=sharing

Comment: `ionic cordova plugin add onesignal-cordova-plugin`
`cordova platform remove android`
`cordova platform add android@10.1.0`
`ionic cordova build android`

Comment: hope it works waiting for your response

Comment: please mark it as a right answer if it's worked for you.....

Comment: now able to get push token id.... Thank you so much!!!